# I want to access parent useState in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Sidebar = ({ sidebarActive, setSidebarActive }) => {

 return (
    <>
      {/* Hamburger button */}
      <button
        className={
          sidebarActive
            ? "hamburgerButton sidebar-oepn"
            : "hamburgerButton sidebar-closed"
        }
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setSidebarActive(!sidebarActive)}
      >
        <i className="fa fa-fw fa-bars" />
      </button>
   </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

when i run i encounter with following error

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR


src\components\VerticalLayout\Sidebar.js
  Line 6:20:  'sidebarActive' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  Line 6:35:  'setSidebarActive' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

if i do the following, i do not encounter with any error but i also didn't get access to parents useState value

```
const Sidebar = (props, { sidebarActive, setSidebarActive }) => {
```

Comment: can you show the code, where you used the Sidebar component?

Comment: The props are passed in as the first argument to the component and *only* the first argument. They aren't somehow split between the first and second arguments as you are trying to read them from.

Comment: Hi Abhinay! 

This issue seems related to eslint and/or typescript.  Can you show how this <Sidebar /> component is consumed. Also, could you create a live example here ? https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

Your first implementation is correct but it showed errors because of [this prop types validation](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md).

According to those errors, your component is lacking [`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). You need to set it like below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Sidebar = ({ sidebarActive, setSidebarActive }) => {

 return (
    <>
      {/* Hamburger button */}
      <button
        className={
          sidebarActive
            ? "hamburgerButton sidebar-oepn"
            : "hamburgerButton sidebar-closed"
        }
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setSidebarActive(!sidebarActive)}
      >
        <i className="fa fa-fw fa-bars" />
      </button>
   </>
  );
};

//set prop types
Sidebar.propTypes = {
   sidebarActive: PropTypes.bool,
   setSidebarActive: PropTypes.func
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Without knowing how the <Sidebar /> component is being consumed, this could only end up fixing the ESLint errors.

Comment: @AndresZapata agreed, I think the author has some eslint setup for this validation, but perhaps this is the first time s/he has faced this problem. I'm trying my best to give a brief idea about what's going on in this error and a possible fix

Answer (score 0):

You just need to validate the props with propTypes:

[Here is a working snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-franklin-cfgr6s?file=/src/App.js)